# Debugging in Chrome: Delete a Function

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome's developer tools, is it possible to delete a function and re-write it?

I have deleted it from the scripts tab and pasted a revised function into the console. But it appears the older function has not been removed from the DOM.

Comment: I'd be surprised if this worked.

Comment: have you tried:   delete myfunction;

Comment: I think this would work if you dig into Resources, then select the script in your Frame, then double clicking the source to edit the code. I believe Chrome will use your edited version as long as you don't have to refresh the page.

Comment: `delete myFunction();` worked. Thanks. So simple.

Comment: Actually -- I get a `true` response when deleting the functions but they still work on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have deleted your function from the Scripts panel, make sure you hit Ctrl-S to actually commit your change. You can also paste the new version of the function in place of the old one in the same script before committing.